# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am trying to fire the error callback in `http-service` file and if any error exists I am calling the data from local service. I am returning this to a service file called `app-config-service`.

Code for `http-service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { MockService } from './mock-service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpRestService {

    constructor(private http:Http,mockService:MockService ) {

    }

    get(pUrl) {
        return this.http.get(pUrl).subscribe(
             function(response) { res => response.json()},
             function(error) { res => this.mockService.userMethods(pUrl) },
             function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
        );
    }

    post(pUrl, pData) {
        return this.http.post(pUrl, pData).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Code for `app-config-service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpRestService } from './http-service';
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
    constructor(private httpRestService: HttpRestService) {
    }
    testAPIMethod(pUrl) {
        return this.httpRestService.get(pUrl).map(res => res);
    }
}
```

As per my knowledge subscribe is used to manipulate the result received, and map is used to copy the data directly without any change.

So I have used subscribe and map in those situations.

I don't know why an error is being triggered as I am a newbie to typescript.

The error is as follows:

```
typescript: E:/ActiveProjects/IonBase/src/services/app-config-service.ts, line: 14
        Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

  L13:  testAPIMethod(pUrl) {
  L14:      return this.httpRestService.get(pUrl).map(res => res);
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I created a live example for your code and add some modifications to bring your to work. Here you see full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-luxw4a
Open console and click to the buttons.

You should change handling in `get`-method and `testAPIMethod`-method. Because the handling of this function is reversed.

Now the explanation:

In your `HttpRestService` you should create only API-Calls. I recommend you to use Observables for API-Calls. Here is an working example for your `HttpRestService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpRestService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(pUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
    .get(pUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  post(pUrl, pData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
    .post(pUrl, pData).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Now you can inject your `HttpRestService` in your `AppConfigService` and subscribe to your `get`-method. Here is example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { HttpRestService } from './http-rest.service';
import { MockService } from './mock.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

  constructor(private httpRestService: HttpRestService,
              private mockService: MockService) {}

  testAPIMethod(pUrl: string) {
    return this.httpRestService.get(pUrl).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Service success');
      console.log(result);
    }, error => {
      console.log('Service failed');
      console.log(error);
      console.log('Run MockService');
      this.mockService.userMethods(pUrl);
    }, () => {
      console.log('Subscription done');
    });
  }
}
```

Ignore `console.log`-outputs, it's only for testing. So in this subscription you can handle the state of this subscription. If API-Call return some result, then you can do something with this. If your API-Call return an error, then you can run alternative calls or local services. If your API-Call was successfull you can use done-state `() => { // done }`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there pay attention to what ur doing on the HttpRestService, 
When the get method called ur return subscription because when u return the .subscribe the subscription returned from the method, instead use:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { MockService } from './mock-service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpRestService {

constructor(private http:Http,mockService:MockService) {}

get(pUrl) {
   return this.http.get(pUrl).map(res => res.json());
}

post(pUrl, pData) {
    return this.http.post(pUrl, pData).map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

and do the subscribe here:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpRestService } from './http-service';
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
constructor(private httpRestService: HttpRestService) {
}
testAPIMethod(pUrl) {
    return this.httpRestService.subscribe(
     (data) => console.log(data),
     (error) => console.log(error)
 );
}
```